# Can I tell bash to run a command after the currently executing command has completed?

Tags: bash, command-line

If I've started a process that turns out to be long-running, can I "queue up" a command to run immediately after it?

I know I can do this with `cmd1 && cmd2` syntax if I was starting from scratch, but what if cmd1 is already running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the currently-running command isn't reading input, you can just type the command in the same window.  Bash will read the input and run the command when the current one finishes.

Comment: Yeah, that's the "If the currently-running command isn't reading input" part, @F.Hauri. :)

Answer (score 13):

You can press C-z to stop the current foreground task, then type "fg %%; some-other-command" to resume the task and run another command afterwards.

Comment: For details of `%%` [see table](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html#JOBIDTABLE) of job identifiers.

Comment: actually this is the correct answer, not the selected one

Answer (score 0):

You can use ';' notation. Check out this link:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=104472

You can either use:

cmd1 && cmd2

Upon cmd1 success, cmd2 will execute. Or:

cmd1 ; cmd2

Upon cmd1 completion, cmd2 will execute no matter what.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; he said that `cmd1` is already running.